# Create an Interface for existing classes?

Tags: c#, design-patterns

I use a `Model` that draws some series on a screen. You can create a Series like `LineSeries` or `CurveSeries` and add them to the Model: `Model.Series.Add(myLineSeries);`. The Series have a property `Points`, where all points are saved, you can easily add some: `myLineSeries.Points.Add(...);`. `Model` takes all series that are inherited from the base class `Series`.

But when i added it to Model and want to add some points later, i have to cast it back:

```
//Model.Series[0].Points does not exists. I have to cast them...

var lineSeries = (Model.Series[0] as LineSeries);

if(lineSeries != null)
    lineSeries.Points.Add(...);

var curveSeries = (Model.Series[0] as CurveSeries);
//Same code for CurveSeries

//Same code for other series types...
```

So i have to do the same code over and over again. If you can access the source code, you can say: lets create a "point interface" or a base class where all have the property points. The series only have to inherit the base class or interface. Now you can say:

```
var Series = (Model.Series[0] as IPointSeries);

//Code only one time :)
```

But now i have no access to the source code of Series and Model. I can not change Model nor series nor abstract series base class implementation.

Is there a common way to do this without changing source code of Model or Series? Like creating a interface for existing series to access them all the same way?

Comment: Can the `Points` collection not be a property on the base class?

Comment: Why your Points property is not in Series abstract class ?

Comment: What do you mean by having no access to the source ? What do you call "the source" ?

Comment: @Sinan I have no access to the source code of the Model and Series means i can not change these.

Comment: @JonEgerton No, because i cannot change the base class and i cannot change the series and model.

Comment: You're saying that you have multiple types of series, they all implement different interfaces that doesn't have a common base, and they all have their own Points collection, and you want 1 piece of code that can handle them all, instead of checking to see if you need to use `LineSeries.Points` or `CurveSeries.Points`, etc. is that right?

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen Yes. I know that all Series i am using will have the Points property.

Comment: Either you write your own wrapper so that the rest of the code doesn't need to know the difference, or you change the classes, or you write the code you've shown in the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write a set of wrapper classes, so that at least you don't have to write all the code knowing about multiple underlying types more than once.

For instance:

```
public class PointSeries
{
    public List<Point> Points { get { return new List<Point>(); } }
}

public class CurveSeries
{
    public List<Point> Points { get { return new List<Point>(); } }
}

public interface ISeriesWrapper
{
    List<Point> Points { get; }
}

public class PointSeriesWrapper : ISeriesWrapper
{
    public PointSeriesWrapper(PointSeries series)
    {
        _Series = series;
    }

    private PointSeries _Series;

    public List<Point> Points { get { return _Series.Points; } }
}

public class CurveSeriesWrapper : ISeriesWrapper
{
    public CurveSeriesWrapper(CurveSeries series)
    {
        _Series = series;
    }

    private CurveSeries _Series;

    public List<Point> Points { get { return _Series.Points; } }
}

public static class SeriesWrapper
{
    public static ISeriesWrapper Create(object series)
    {
        var pointSeries = series as PointSeries;
        if (pointSeries != null)
            return new PointSeriesWrapper(pointSeries);

        var curveSeries = series as CurveSeries;
        if (curveSeries != null)
            return new CurveSeriesWrapper(curveSeries);

        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }
}
```

Example of usage:

```
var pointSeries = SeriesWrapper.Create(Model.Series[0]);
lineSeries.Points.AddRange(pointSeries.Points);
```

Comment: The best way would probably be to change the actual classes in use, but OP said this was not an option. As such, my next best idea would be to wrap it into something I can control.