# Interface over java classes

Tags: java

I am coding something which uses the `javax.xml.bind` package to look for `Annotations` such as `@XMLElement`, `@XMLElementRef`and `@XMLAttribute`. All three of these classes have a `required()` method which returns a boolean, which I need to check for. Therefore I do :

```
Boolean required;
for (Annotation anno : theAnnotations) {
    if (anno.annotationType().equals(XmlElement.class)) {
        required = ((XmlElement) anno).required();
    }
    else if (anno.annotationType().equals(XmlElementRef.class)) {
        required = ((XmlElementRef) anno).required();
    }
    else if (anno.annotationType().equals(XmlAttribute.class)) {
        required = ((XmlAttribute) anno).required();
    }               
}
```

This code seems uselessly repetitive. I would like to create an Interface over  `XMLElement`, `XMLElementRef`and `XMLAttribute`, to specify that these three have a `required()` method. That way I could just do :

```
for (Annotation anno : theAnnotations) {
    required = ((MyInterface) anno).required();             
}
```

Obviously I do not have access to the source code of `javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement`, `XMLElementRef`and `XMLAttribute`. Is there any way to tell the compiler that these built-in classes implement MyInterface ?

I found the following C# question : [Create an Interface for existing classes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25182088/create-an-interface-for-existing-classes) which seems close, but I'm not sure I can read C# well and the idea of wrapper classes doesn't seem to adapt to my use.

Comment: If they all have a `required()` method that does the same thing, why not make a parent class they all extend from?

Comment: @Danny I assume that his point is that he can't access those classes to change them.

Comment: No, it is not possible to "modify" the structure of a given class in Java. And there is no support for "duck typing" either. So you are pretty much stuck with the answer you got now (creating your own custom wrappers for these "fixed" classes") ... what might work or not work when talking about such a framework.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, idea of wrapper classes is applicable. Below sample Java code (consider classes `XML` and `XML2` to be unmodifiable):

```
class XML {
    void commonMethod() {}
}
class XML2 {
    void commonMethod() {}
}
// all code from here is under your control
interface XMLAdapter {
    void commonMethod();
}
class XMLWrapper implements XMLAdapter {
    private final XML impl;

    XMLWrapper(XML impl) {
        this.impl = impl;
    }

    @Override
    public void commonMethod() {
        impl.commonMethod();
    }
}
class XMLWrapper2 implements XMLAdapter {
    private final XML2 impl;

    XMLWrapper2(XML2 impl) {
        this.impl = impl;
    }

    @Override
    public void commonMethod() {
        impl.commonMethod();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer. Wrapper classes are much clearer to me now. Now, to sort my list of `Annotations` into `XMLWrapper`'s and `XMLWrapper2`'s, I still need to check whether they are `XML1`'s or `XML2`'s, don't I ? Doesn't it defeat the purpose of avoiding the first code repetition ?

Answer (score 0):

Worst case scenario you can make an enum

```
public enum XmlAnnotationTypes {
    XML_ELEMENT(XmlElement.class),
    XML_ELEMENT_REF(XmlElementRef.class),
    XML_ATTRIBUTE(XmlAttribute.class);

    private Class<?> clazz;

    private XmlAnnotationTypes(Class<?> clazz) {
        this.clazz = clazz;
    }

    public Class<?> getClazz() {
        return clazz;
    }
}

for(Annotation anno : theAnnotations) {
    for(XmlAnnotationTypes xmlAnnoType : XmlAnnotationtypes.values()) {
        if(xmlAnnoType.getClazz() == anno.annotationType()) {
            try {
                 Method method =  xmlAnnoType.getClazz().getMethod("required");
                 method.setAccessible(true);
                 required = (Boolean)method.invoke(anno);
            } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Or just do what Victor said and make an adapter class that contains the class you want to encapsulate, have a common interface for these three container classes, then if the contained class's `class` is what you are looking for, invoke the `required() wrapper` in the adapter around the `required()` of the contained class. To be fair, that's the less hacky-tacky solution.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Judging from your answer and Victor's, it seems that I _cannot_ avoid checking for the annotation's actual class, but that I _can_ avoid using a "different" method in each of the three cases.

Comment: That's what it seems to me as well, yes.